# Do I need to update initramfs on every kernel recompilation?

Tags: linux-kernel, gentoo, initramfs

Suppose that:

- any kernel configuration regarding initramfs (loading external initramfs support and compression)
- No RAID or lvm used
- rootfs uses `ext4`

Is it really necessary to generate a new `initramfs` after I recompile the same kernel?

Comment: Fully modular kernel and all dependencies resolved by Initramfs generator is the common approach. Alternative approach like [Custom Initramfs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs), it's possible with non-modular kernel, or by providing dependencies in a separate file; it's just very uncommon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initramfs contains kernel modules; so if anything has changed in the modules included in your initramfs, you need to generate a new one.

Other than that, for the same kernel version, no, you shouldn’t need to generate a new initramfs if you already have one.

Comment: I extracted the `initramfs-5.*.image` and found it only contains 4 modules while my `/lib/modules` contains 172 modules. Does this mean that as long as that 4 modules aren't changed, I don't need to update initramfs?

Comment: Yup, that’s right.

Comment: Thx for the clearification.